# Android - Path does not draw

Tags: android, path

I am trying to simply draw a path in Android and I am running into the unfortunate situation of the path not drawing for unbeknownst reasons..
When I try to simply draw a line it works fine. When I try running the code below nothing gets drawn but the program still runs.

Code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class GameView extends View {
    Paint p = new Paint();
    //int initX;
    //int initY;
    //int endX;
    //int endY;
    Path path = new Path();

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet as) {
        super(context, as);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        /* one-time initialization stuff */
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.space);
    }


    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        /* called each time this View is drawn */

        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        p.setStrokeWidth(2);
        //c.drawLines(pts, p);
        c.drawPath(path, p);
        path.close();
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            path.moveTo(e.getX(), e.getY());
            //path.lineTo(e.getX(), e.getY());
            invalidate(); // force redraw
            return true;
        }

        else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            path.lineTo(e.getX(), e.getY());
            path.moveTo(e.getX(), e.getY());
            invalidate(); // force redraw
            return true;
        }

        else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            path.lineTo(e.getX(), e.getY());
            invalidate(); // force redraw
            return true;
        }
            return false;
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is your code doesn't  specify the begin and the end of your path and need some declaration for canvas to prepare it for drawing change your `onDraw` method like :

```
 public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    /* called each time this View is drawn */

    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    p.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    c.drawPaint(p);
    for (int i = 50; i < 100; i++) {
        path.moveTo(i, i-1);
        path.lineTo(i, i);  
 }
    p.setColor(Color.RED);
    p.setStrokeWidth(2);
    //c.drawLines(pts, p);
    path.close();
    p.setStrokeWidth(3);
    p.setPathEffect(null);
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    c.drawPath(path, p);
}
```

I add some styles from my old code feel free to remove or change it , feed me back in any not obvious things